# Como passar itens de um [object Object] para o json pai

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Olá o servidor está me retornando o seguinte json

```
this.itens  = { 
   id: '',
   data: '',
   hora: '',

   cliente:{
   nome: '',
   cpf: ''
   }
}
```

eu preciso que os dados do cliente nao fique em um segundo json mas em um campo ex `clienteNome: ''` dentro do this.itens esse é só um exemplo genérico.

Comment: E o cpf?.......

Comment: corrigido é um campo de cliente

Comment: sim, mas vc quer pegar só o nome? E o cpf?

Comment: eu quero pegar qlqr dado é só um exemplo genérico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar novas entradas no primeiro nível do objeto e deletar a chave `cliente`:

```js
this.itens  = { 
   id: '1',
   data: '24/06/2018',
   hora: '19:03:00',

   cliente:{
   nome: 'Fulano de Tal',
   cpf: '123456789-01'
   }
}

itens['clienteNome'] = itens.cliente.nome; // cria nova chame e atribui o nome
itens['clienteCpf'] = itens.cliente.cpf; // cria nova chave e atribui o CPF

delete itens['cliente']; // apagar a chave "cliente" do objeto

console.log(itens);
```

Resultado:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "data": "24/06/2018",
  "hora": "19:03:00",
  "clienteNome": "Fulano de Tal",
  "clienteCpf": "123456789-01"
}
```

Ou você pode iterar o objeto usando `for...in` para criar as entradas de forma automática. Só que neste caso você não irá poderá definir o nome da chave como `clienteNome` etc., a não ser que use vários `if`s dentro do laço para dar nomes diferentes de acordo com o dado:

```js
this.itens  = { 
   id: '1',
   data: '24/06/2018',
   hora: '19:03:00',

   cliente:{
   nome: 'Fulano de Tal',
   cpf: '123456789-01'
   }
}

for(var item in itens.cliente){
   itens[item] = itens.cliente[item];
}

delete itens['cliente'];

console.log(itens);
```

Outra forma é mesclar o objeto aninhado `cliente` com o o pai `itens`:

```js
this.itens  = { 
   id: '1',
   data: '24/06/2018',
   hora: '19:03:00',

   cliente:{
   nome: 'Fulano de Tal',
   cpf: '123456789-01'
   }
}

Object.assign(itens, itens.cliente);
delete itens['cliente'];

console.log(itens);
```

Ou pode usar o [operador spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) do ES6 (*não suportado pelos navegadores da Microsoft*):

```js
this.itens  = { 
   id: '1',
   data: '24/06/2018',
   hora: '19:03:00',

   cliente:{
   nome: 'Fulano de Tal',
   cpf: '123456789-01'
   }
}

itens = {...itens, ...itens.cliente};
delete itens['cliente'];

console.log(itens);
```

Comment: muito obrigado!